# How can water jets generate no heat?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature

Water jet machining uses high velocity water jets, but we are told that there is no heat generated in the object being cut.

Why is this so?

Won't there be a temperature change in the molecules of the object by the bombardment of the water molecules against the object?

If heat is not generated how is it being cut?

Any suggestions will be valued

Comment: I think the point is that the amount of heat generated is so small that the temperature rise is not noticeable.

Comment: The root mean square velocity of molecules at room temperature is several hundred m/s. The speed of the jet as a whole is perhaps in the ballpark of 100 m/s, holding an order of magnitude or more lower kinetic energy than its internal energy. It is a shockwave that happens due to the sudden impact of the water jet on the machined part that literally tears material off.